# Logitech webcam blurry in multiple apps (Zoom, VLC)

Tags: drivers, display-resolution, webcam, logitech, streaming

I have a 720p webcam (Logitech C270) that has worked fine on macOS for years. However, it's displaying really low resolution (240p?) in both Zoom and VLC on Ubuntu 22.04.

*Choppy edges when capturing in VLC:*

[image]

*Driver info says `uvcvideo`, which matches this old compatibility matrix https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsMultimediaWebCamerasLogitech*

```
$ v4l2-ctl --info --device /dev/video0

Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Card type        : UVC Camera (046d:0825)
    Bus info         : usb-0000:00:14.0-7
    Driver version   : 5.19.17
    Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
        Video Capture
        Metadata Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps      : 0x04200001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Model            : UVC Camera (046d:0825)
    Serial           : 91E067A0
    Bus info         : usb-0000:00:14.0-7
    Media version    : 5.19.17
    Hardware revision: 0x00000012 (18)
    Driver version   : 5.19.17
Interface Info:
    ID               : 0x03000002
    Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
    ID               : 0x00000001 (1)
    Name             : UVC Camera (046d:0825)
    Function         : V4L2 I/O
    Flags            : default
    Pad 0x01000007   : 0: Sink
      Link 0x02000019: from remote pad 0x100000a of entity 'Extension 4' (Video Pixel Formatter): Data, Enabled, Immutable
```

- In zoom config I've tried turning off autoscale and other commonly reported settings
- In vlc i've tried manually entering 1280x720 dimensions and the framerate says 60
- youtube videos display just fine, so i don't think it's a video card issue

Trying to switch to Linux as my daily driver <3